# Installer4j: dir/jre/bin/java: not found?

Tags: linux, install4j

I am using

```
install4j version 5.1.6 (build 5598), built on 2013-06-12
```

to create installers for my project for different platforms. We provide our own JRE bundles.

Until now, the JRE we were providing is `1.6` and yesterday I upgraded to bundle `JRE 1.8` with our installers.

I created installers for different platforms, and when I try to install it on `Linux`, I see

```
sh shnlp_unix_0_20_0-SNAPSHOT.sh
Unpacking JRE ...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/shnlps: file does not exist
Starting Installer ...
shnlp_unix_0_20_0-SNAPSHOT.sh: 489: shnlp_unix_0_20_0-SNAPSHOT.sh: /home/harit/downloads/shnlp_unix_0_20_0-SNAPSHOT.sh.25207.dir/jre/bin/java: not found
```

What has changed?

Comment: Did you create the JRE bundle yourself?

Comment: The the bundle structure is invalid for some reason. You can untar it and check if bin/java is contained.

Comment: would upgrading to Install4j version 6 will handle JRE 8 bundles?

Comment: 5.1.6 should handle Java 1.8 bundles as well, but it's worth a try